# Store each row in a resultset as an object in an array

Tags: java, sql, arrays, loops, resultset

Essentially my problem is that I am returning a resultset from a jdbc query and i want to store each row as an object in an array. when i try to loop through the resultset- it only saves on object in the array- i suppose this is obviously due to the fact that the while loop is within the for loop- i have tried re-jigging the loops a few times but with no joy.
Would be great to find a less complex and convuluted way of getting the objects passed into the array.

```
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
    Check c = new Check();
    rs.last();
    int numberOfRows = rs.getRow(); 
    Check checkArray [] = new Check [numberOfRows]; 
    rs.beforeFirst();

    for (int i = 0; i < checkArray.length; i++)
    {
     while (rs.next())
     {
    c.setAmount(rs.getBigDecimal("AMOUNT"));
    c.setCheckNumber(rs.getString("CHECKNUMBER"));
    c.setComments(rs.getString("COMMENTS"));
    c.setId(rs.getLong("SETID"));
    c.setMailTo(rs.getString("MAILTO"));
    c.setPayTo(rs.getString("PAYTO"));
    c.setProcessed(rs.getBoolean("PROCESSED"));
    checkArray[i]= c;
}
}
```

Comment: I think it would be quite a bit easier to use an arrayList but unfortunately I must return an array of the check type.

Answer (score 0):

Try combining the loops:

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
rs.last();
int numberOfRows = rs.getRow(); 
Check checkArray [] = new Check [numberOfRows]; 
rs.beforeFirst();

while (numberOfRows > 0 && rs.next()) {
    Check c = new Check();
    c.setAmount(rs.getBigDecimal("AMOUNT"));
    c.setCheckNumber(rs.getString("CHECKNUMBER"));
    ...
    checkArray[i]= c;
    numberOfRows--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless your `ResultSet` is an instance of `CachedRowSet`, it won't know how many rows there are and will return a zero from `.getRow()`

The main problem with your code is that you are *reusing* the *same* Check instance over and over, meaning all elements of your array are the *same* Check object. You ned to create a new instance for *every* row

Better load all rows into a `List` and use `while (resultSet.next())` to control to loop.

If you absolutely need an array, convert the List to an array at the end with `List.toArray()`

An abbreviated version of the code is:

```
List<Check> list = new ArrayList<Check>();

while (rs.next()) {
    Check c = new Check();
    // set fields of c
    list.add(c);
}

Check[] checkArray = list.toArray();
```

Comment: Please tell me there is a class-agnostic way of doing this.  Having to write lines of code for each of the properties is terrible.

Comment: @haxor what do you mean? way of doing what exactly?

Comment: The while (rs.next()) loop - you have to iterate over each of the class members you want to store.  I was hoping there was a way to dump the ResultSet directly to a List<Object> that you could then manage using Reflection.

Answer (score 0):

`ResultSet`has getArray function so you could use like that.

```
    checkArray[i]= rs.getArray(int columnIndex);
```

Comment: cant extend Check unfortunately

Comment: its rows im making objects from, not arrays