# Java ResultSet copy to generic object or list

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I'm aware of the issues with using ResultSet and have seen examples about extracting data into an object (or list), however, I'm wanting to do this in a generic manner i.e. without having to be aware of the class.

Is there a way to do this such that the result would be an Object or List that I could then iterate using Reflection?

The solutions I've examined that either don't seem to work or require class awareness of the target class include:

- [How to copy resultset into object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14929818/how-to-copy-resultset-into-object)
- [Copying Java ResultSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817785/copying-java-resultset)

I've also tried ResultSetMapper (http://resultsetmapper.sourceforge.net/) and it seems to require the class as well.  I really just want an Object or List that I can act on.

Comment: More examples requiring lines of code specific to each of the object's properties; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17206523/put-resultset-values-into-collection-object-then-add-to-arraylist and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440482/store-each-row-in-a-resultset-as-an-object-in-an-array - any way to do this where the output is a List<Object> instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is pretty generic:

```java
Statement st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Clients WHERE ID <= 2");

// collect column names
List<String> columnNames = new ArrayList<>();
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
for (int i = 1; i <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++) {
    columnNames.add(rsmd.getColumnLabel(i));
}

int rowIndex = 0;
while (rs.next()) {
    rowIndex++;
    // collect row data as objects in a List
    List<Object> rowData = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        rowData.add(rs.getObject(i));
    }
    // for test purposes, dump contents to check our results
    // (the real code would pass the "rowData" List to some other routine)
    System.out.printf("Row %d%n", rowIndex);
    for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < rsmd.getColumnCount(); colIndex++) {
        String objType = "null";
        String objString = "";
        Object columnObject = rowData.get(colIndex);
        if (columnObject != null) {
            objString = columnObject.toString() + " ";
            objType = columnObject.getClass().getName();
        }
        System.out.printf("  %s: %s(%s)%n",
                columnNames.get(colIndex), objString, objType);
    }
}
```

For my test data (in SQL Server) it prints the following to the console:

```
Row 1
  ID: 1 (java.lang.Integer)
  LastName: Thompson (java.lang.String)
  FirstName: Gord (java.lang.String)
  DOB: (null)
Row 2
  ID: 2 (java.lang.Integer)
  LastName: Loblaw (java.lang.String)
  FirstName: Bob (java.lang.String)
  DOB: 1966-09-12 16:03:00.0 (java.sql.Timestamp)
```

Comment: Thanks for providing this Gord - I'll certainly give it a try.  I'm a bit constrained in that I need a List<Object> to pass to another function that I don't control.  Do you know of a solution that produces a List<Object> or will convert Maps cleanly?

Comment: Use a List<Map> instead of Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Object>>

Comment: @haxor I have updated my answer to use `List<Object>`.

Comment: Hi Gord - thanks.  In your example is each of the rows a separate Object or a separate List<Object>?  I would assume each row to be an object but that's not what I get from your code output.  Nevertheless this is really, really helpful (marking as answer).  Is your code easily modifiable to have each row be an Object and a List<Object> containing all of them?

Comment: @haxor re: "Is your code easily modifiable to have each row be an Object and a List<Object> containing all of them?" - Well, an `ArrayList` object is an `Object` itself, so you could conceivably add each `rowData` object to another ArrayList named `tblData`. Then, depending on how precise you want your terminology to be you could say that each row is an `Object` (an `ArrayList` object) and the `List` of row "Objects" (named `tblData`) is a `List<Object>`.

Comment: Yes, but what I meant was using reflection to build a discrete 'Object' for each row in the ResultSet, and then add those Objects to a List<Object>.  Cheers